# Progression and Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $p$ and $q$ be the roots of the equation $x^2-2x+A=0$ and let $r$ and $s$ be the roots of the equation $x^2-18x+B=0$.

If $p < q< r< s$ are in AP, then find the value of A and B. (JEE advance 1997)

Comment: You have an unfinished sentence. Please check that!

Comment: Hint: $p+q=2\implies 2p+M=2$ where $M$ is the period of the progression.  Similarly $r+s=18\implies 2p+5M=18$.

Comment: Please solve further and tell me the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p,\space q,\space r,\space s$ be $(a-3d), (a-d), (a+d), (a+3d)$ respectively as they are in A.P.

Now from the first quadratic equation
$$p+q=2\implies2a-4d=2\implies a-2d=1$$

From second quadratic equation
$$r+s=18\implies 2a+4d=18\implies a+2d=9$$

From above equations
$$a=5,\space d = 2$$

$$\therefore p = -1,\space q = 3,\space r = 7,\space s = 11$$

Hence
$$A = p\cdot q = -3$$$$B = r\cdot s = 77$$